# find all the indices of all the duplicate elements in Array

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab

> Given an Integer array, find all the indices of all the duplicate elements in it.
>
> For example, consider `A = [4, 12, 9, 8, 9, 12, 7, 1]`. Since 12 and 9 have duplicates, all their indices will be returned i.e. `d = [2, 3, 5, 6]`. The length of `A` is below 200 and the integer elements are between 1 and 5000.

Currently I am using the following function. However to meet my requirements, this function is slowing me down. Is there any possible performance improvement ?

```matlab
function d = fincDuplicates(A)
    U = unique(A);
    [co,ce] = hist(A,U);
    an = ce(co>1);
    d=[];
    for i=1:numel(an)
        d=[d,find(A==an(i))];
    end
end
```

Comment: Profiler shows that this function is using 60% of total time (Sorry I cannot share my entire code). The function `unique` and `hist` are the main cause. Here I am calling `hist` to find the frequency of unique  elements in the array. And finding indices of elements with frequency more than 1.

Comment: A very short but highly memory inificient solution, that can be useful in your case where length(A) < 200: `d = find(sum(A==A.')>1)`

Comment: @obchardon Till now, yours is the best solution. Fastest when length(A)<100.

Comment: @obchardon, I keep getting `Error using  == , Matrix dimensions must agree.` if I try your method. What am I missing ? Does it rely on implicit expansion ?

Comment: @Hoki indeed it involve implicit expansion (matlab R2016b and above / Octave 3.6.0 and above).

Comment: yup, I tried to mimic that with explicit expansion (only have R2016a) but the performance is not great. I wonder if the new implicit expansion is faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Edits:*

1: Code corrected for edge case highlighted in comment, benchmark updated.

2: Added 'expansion' solution to benchmark (had to reduce max N element to 20000).

3: Added `accumarray` method to benchmark (*Winner for high N*), and `sparse` method.

---

Here's another way to get the result, without using the function `unique` or `hist`.
It does relly on the function `sort`.

In an expanded form (if you want to see the result of the intermediate steps):

```
A = [4, 12, 9, 8, 9, 12, 7, 1] ;

[B,I] = sort(A) ;    % this will put duplicate elements side by side
df = diff(B) ;       % the duplicates will return '0' when substracted
dx = find(df==0) ;   % find their indices

% Since each duplicate concerns 2 elemts of the array, we add the next
% index for each "flagged" index, taking care not to duplicate the indices
% of sucessive duplicates.
if ~isempty(dx)
    dd = [diff(dx)~=1 , true] ;
    dx = [dx dx(dd)+1] ;
    d = I(dx)   % get the original position of the duplicates in original array
else
    d=[] ;
end
```

Which you could compact to:

```
[B,I] = sort(A) ;
dx = find(diff(B)==0) ;
if ~isempty(dx)
    d = I([dx dx([diff(dx)~=1,true])+1]) ;
else
    d = [] ;
end
```

gives:

```
d =
     3     2     5     6
```

Personnaly I would also `sort` the returned indices but if it's not necessary and you're concerned about performance you can just accept the unsorted result.

---

Here's another benchmark (testing the number of element from 10 to 20000):

*run on MATLAB R2016a*

[image: bench]

And the code for it:

```
function ExecTimes = benchmark_findDuplicates

nOrder = (1:9).' * 10.^(1:3) ; nOrder = [nOrder(:) ; 10000 ; 20000 ] ;
npt = numel(nOrder) ;

ExecTimes = zeros(npt,6) ;

for k = 1:npt
    % Sample data
    N = nOrder(k) ;
    A = randi(5000,[1,N]) ;

    % Benchmark
    f1 = @() findDuplicates_histMethod(A) ;
    f2 = @() findDuplicates_histcountMethod(A) ;
    f3 = @() findDuplicates_sortMethod(A) ;
    f4 = @() findDuplicates_expansionMethod(A) ;
    f5 = @() findDuplicates_accumarrayMethod(A) ;
    f6 = @() findDuplicates_sparseMethod(A) ;
    ExecTimes(k,1) = timeit( f1 ) ;
    ExecTimes(k,2) = timeit( f2 ) ;
    ExecTimes(k,3) = timeit( f3 ) ;
    ExecTimes(k,4) = timeit( f4 ) ;
    ExecTimes(k,5) = timeit( f5 ) ;
    ExecTimes(k,6) = timeit( f6 ) ;

    clear A
    disp(N)
end

function d = findDuplicates_histMethod(A)
    U = unique(A);
    [co,ce] = hist(A,U);
    an = ce(co>1);
    d=[];
    for i=1:numel(an)
        d=[d,find(A==an(i))];
    end
end

function d = findDuplicates_histcountMethod(A)
    [~,idxu,idxc] = unique(A);
    [count, ~, idxcount] = histcounts(idxc,numel(idxu));
    idxkeep = count(idxcount)>1;
    idx_A = 1:length(A);
    d = idx_A(idxkeep);
end

function d = findDuplicates_sortMethod(A)
    [B,I] = sort(A) ;
    dx = find(diff(B)==0) ;
    if ~isempty(dx)
        d = I([dx dx([diff(dx)~=1,true])+1]) ;
    else
        d=[];
    end
end

function d = findDuplicates_expansionMethod(A)
    Ae = ones(numel(A),1) * A ;
    d = find(sum(Ae==Ae.')>1) ;
end

function d = findDuplicates_accumarrayMethod(A)
    d = find(ismember(A, find(accumarray(A(:), 1)>1))) ;
end

function d = findDuplicates_sparseMethod(A)
    d = find(ismember(A, find(sparse(A, 1, 1)>1)));
end

end
```

Comment: There is a big flaw in here. For `A=[1,2,4,1,2,5,1,2,6];`, answer is `d=[1,4,7,2,5,8]`. However it returns, `d=[1,4,2,5,4,7,5,8]`. Funny how we all started benchmarking without testing all testcases.

Comment: ouch, that's the right indices ... but also duplicated. Damn! Running `unique` on the output would surely put a dent in the performance. Can't try it just now, feel free to edit if you do.

Comment: @impopularGuy, that's it corrected. By using `unique` the solution was getting less performant than the `histcount` method at very high number of elements, but by reusing the same trick to detect duplicate in the original array and in the array of duplicate indices, I managed to keep the solution execution time under the others.

Comment: Could you add my `accumarray`-based solution to the benchmarking?

Comment: @LuisMendo, done. And as often from you, top solution for high N ;-)

Comment: @Hoki Thanks! `accumarray` always delivers :-D

Comment: @Hoki For MATLAB versions that supports Implicit expansion, it is the winner for low N.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the party, but this question is begging for an **[`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)-based** solution :-)

```
d = find(ismember(A, find(accumarray(A(:), 1)>1)));
```

This exploits the fact that `A` contains small, positive integers, so they can be interpreted as indices. **It works as follows**:

```
                          accumarray(A(:), 1)      % count of occurrences of each value
                     find(                   >1)   % values occurring more than once
d = find(ismember(A,                            ); % their positions in A
```

**Alternatively, [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)** can be used instead of `accumarray`:

```
d = find(ismember(A, find(sparse(A, 1, 1)>1)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution (credit: this was adapted from https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/175086-finding-non-unique-values-in-an-array)

```
A = [4, 12, 9, 8, 9, 12, 7, 1];
[~,idxu,idxc] = unique(A);
[count, ~, idxcount] = histcounts(idxc,numel(idxu));
idxkeep = count(idxcount)>1;
idx_A = 1:length(A);
idx_dup = idx_A(idxkeep);
```

It gives the following:

```
>> idx_dup = idx_A(idxkeep)

idx_dup =

     2     3     5     6
```

Not sure if it's more or less efficient than your current solution. You probably need to test it with realistic data.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution now uses around 70% of total time.

Comment: @impopularGuy oh well, it was worth a shot. Is the total time the same though? Becase if the total time has substantially decreased, 70% of it might still be faster than 60% of a much longer time.

Comment: My implementation took around 15secs, yours took around 19secs.

Comment: @impopularGuy that is strange, I measure completely the opposite, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: it must depend on array size

Comment: @impopularGuy yes of course it does. This is why I tested a wide range and provided code so you can do the same. Still, yours is slowest, always.

Comment: I know mine is slowest. That is why I posted the question.

Comment: @impopularGuy ah. You contradicted that statement 4 coments above, this is why I was mentioning it. Must be a typo then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215220/discussion-between-impopularguy-and-ander-biguri).

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here its the results of the other answers, compared to yours, and yours accelerated (which I was working on before better people came to your rescue). For the sizes in your question:

```
for ii=1:100
    a=randi(5000,1,200);
    t1(ii)=timeit(@()yours(a));

    a=randi(5000,1,200);
    t2(ii)=timeit(@()faster(a));

    a=randi(5000,1,200);
    t3(ii)=timeit(@()hoki(a));

    a=randi(5000,1,200);
    t4(ii)=timeit(@()am304(a));
end
disp(['Faster: x', num2str(mean(t1)/mean(t2))])
disp(['hoki: x', num2str(mean(t1)/mean(t3))])
disp(['am304: x', num2str(mean(t1)/mean(t4))])
disp(['Faster: x', num2str(t1/t2)])
disp(['hoki: x', num2str(t1/t3)])
disp(['am304: x', num2str(t1/t4)])
function d = yours(A)
    U = unique(A);
    [co,ce] = hist(A,U);
    an = ce(co>1);
    d=[];
    for i=1:numel(an)
        d=[d,find(A==an(i))];
    end
end

function d = faster(A)
    [co] = histcounts(A,max(A));
    an = co>1;
    d=[];
    for i=1:numel(an)
        d=[d,find(A==an(i))];
    end
end

function res=am304(A)
[~,idxu,idxc] = unique(A);
[count, ~, idxcount] = histcounts(idxc,numel(idxu));
idxkeep = count(idxcount)>1;
idx_A = 1:length(A);
res = idx_A(idxkeep);
end

function res=hoki(A)
[B,I] = sort(A) ;
dx = find(diff(B)==0) ;
res = I([dx dx+1]) ;
end
```

The results are:

```
Faster: x0.0054505
hoki: x7.4142
am304: x1.0881
```

My faster version fails miserably for this case.

I get that Hoki's answer is the fastest by a small margin in large arrays, but much faster in small ones, and that depending on the size and range of `a`, it is 2~30 times faster (together with am304's answer).

Comment: Awesome. However this kind of measurement cannot be trusted. It would be better if we could generate a new random array for each separate call of the functions.

Comment: @impopularGuy I haven't posted any specific times so you can copy paste 3 lines yourself ;) Still the same results btw.

Comment: @impopularGuy if you are generating a new random array for each separate call of the functions, then you are not comparing like for like. To compare the performance of the functions, they need to operate on the same data, otherwise it's pointless.

Comment: @am304 did it for 100 repetitions now, so hopefully the differences should average out.

Comment: @am304 of course they need to operate on same data. i might not have been able to explain properly.

Comment: @impopularGuy you have. am304's point is that if you change the data, the comparison its not valid anymore. He has a point.